# When to use TLS for a database

Tags: security, ssl

I've found other answers to my question on StackOverflow, but they are old, and things have changed a lot when it comes to security.

I would like a year 2017 re-evaluation of the answer to this question:

Inside my company, should my database require TLS connections from our internal client applications?  My database has customer data that would constitute a Yahoo-sized public relations disaster if it leaked.  But my client applications are firewall'd away from any public internet access.

TLS is used to prevent someone from sniffing traffic.  But from my understanding (correct me if I'm wrong) the only way sniffing traffic is possible is to be a root user on the source or destination server.  (assuming we don't have shared Ethernet hubs and such)

The may be be another way to sniff traffic if someone has direct physical access to the network switches in our datacenter.

But trying to protect ourselves against root users and datacenter employees seems overkill to me, especially given that TLS does come at a considerable cost in terms of performance, complexity, and maintainability.

Or is this just one of those situations where we need to be absolute in our security choices rather than try to reason cost-benefit, because cost-benefit is impossible to calculate accurately when it comes to security breaches anyway?

Thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using TLS for an internal network helps simplify the threat model.  More would have to go wrong in order for the transmitted data to be leaked to an adversary.

An adversary who has compromised any system on the same network as the database can use [ARP spoofing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARP_spoofing) to reroute traffic. From a threat modeling perspective, this increases the attack surface, and every system on the same network needs to have the same security guarantee.  Many routers have a configuration option that protects the ARP table from such attacks - and this option can be disabled by a firmware update. Using TLS is defense-in-depth because this measure protects core assets, even when other systems fail.

Comment: Thank you, you've described the situation eloquently.  :)  Yes, it does add one more piece of security to many-piece web of security.  But I still feel the need to attach some value to that, and compare it to the cost of using TLS.  Maybe that's not a realistic thing to desire when it comes to security though.  :/